# How to see local vs. remote branch state in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I like IDEA's Git UI but one important piece of info is missing, the one that is shown by the `git status` command - the state of the local vs. remote branch (not the locally modified files), e.g.

> Your branch and 'origin/xyz' have diverged,
> and have 1 and 2 different commits each, respectively.

Is there a way to see it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the bottom right side of the IntelliJ click branch name.
Then click one of your remote branches and then click `Compare with current`

Comment: thanks, that does it but still many clicks for such a basic info...